# How to click on links which has similar text?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a page containing 100 links having the same text "Results". How can I click on these links one by one? Please suggest me a selenium webdriver script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you're working in Java:**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public void clickLinks(final String url,final String linkText) throws Exception
{
    WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    webDriver.get(url);
    List<WebElement> links = webDriver.findElements(By.linkText(linkText));
    for (WebElement link : links)
        link.click();
    webDriver.quit();
}
```

**If you're working in Python:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

def clickLinks(url,linkText):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
    browser.get(url)
    links = browser.find_elements_by_link_text(linkText)
    for link in links:
        link.click()
    browser.quit()
```

### UPDATE:

I doubt that you are unable to click the links before scrolling the page down (as you mention in your comment). Perhaps you are unable to find the links... In any case, if you want to scroll the page all the way down, then here is how you can do it:

Java: `webDriver.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")`.

Python: `browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")`.

You can replace `document.body.scrollHeight` with some numeric value in order to scroll it partially.

Comment: Thanks for the post barak.

Comment: Barak, I have one more clarifications. Now, I am able to click all links - this is first set but, next set of links will be displayed only on scrolling down the page. Do you know how to exexute this?

Comment: No problem. If you like the answer, then why note vote for it? Regarding your new problem, please see my updated answer above.